# Grammatical constraint of language

Tags: terminology, english, grammar

I have a question for a machine translation exam which reads;

"Provide examples where unigram, brigram, trigram and 4-gram models would fail to capture a grammatical constraint of the English language."

Can anybody give examples of what grammatical constraints are as I don't have a clue...

Comment: In the sentence, "**Mary**, though **she** is very tired by the end of the day, slowly and carefully **finishes** all the assignments.", the agreement between **Mary** (or **she**, both singular) and **finishes** (verb calls for singular subject) cannot  be handled by a 4-gram model because these words are more than 4 words apart. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

A grammatical constraint is a "rule" that prohibits speakers from building a particular kind of sentence. For example, you can't say in standard English *he go to school*, or *to he goes school*, etc. What they are asking you (if I understand the question correctly) is to provide examples of these kinds of constraints that a n-gram based grammar would miss. An example that comes to mind is that of long distance relations and structural closeness. If you need specific examples I could give you a couple.

Comment: For example: _President Obama has visited Los Angeles_ is perfectly grammatical, but _*President Nixon has visited Los Angeles_ is not. Because President Nixon is dead, and the perfect construction does not allow subjects that are both human and dead. It would take a very intuitive N-gram model to capture this.

Comment: @jlawler: That's a semantic constraint. Nothing ungrammatical about it at all. Just like "unicorns are cool" doesn't become ungrammatical just because unicorns don't really exist.

Comment: @jlawler, so you can't say that a human "has died"? Sounds OK to me.

Comment: The [Hot News](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) sense of the perfect is fine, but only if it's recent. And whether it's a grammatical constraint or a semantic one is quite irrelevant to what an Ngram-based grammar could recognize. Unless you want to define "grammatical constraint" as "anything an Ngram-based grammar could recognize".

Comment: Many sentences in print about Nixon when he was alive became ungrammatical upon his death? I should quote Chomsky on grammar vs. semantics: "Colorful green ideas sleep furiously".

Comment: That's not a fully "grammatical" constraint, it is a semantic-grammatical constraint. A good example of a case where n-grams fail are embedded sentences. In a sentences like *the man who is swimming in the ocean since yesterday, and that has a blue shirt, has herpes* will make the model fail at finding the main verb of the sentence, for say, translating it into another language correctly, or whatever.

Comment: Should we ask the OP to clarify whether they're interested in all kinds of things that n-grams cannot cope with or whether actual constraints specific only to grammar are what's important? That may mean re-wording the question...

Comment: The accurate quote from Chomsky is ["**Colorless**` green ideas sleep furiously`"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).

Comment: @babou: D'oh! Can't believe I typed that wrong when it was right in my head (-: